# ModSecurity OWASP CRS 3.3.0 false positives on a Wordpress site

Tags: owasp, mod-security

The following search queries are blocked by ModSecurity and returns a 403 forbidden error:

`www.example.com/s=zip+someword` &
`www.example.com/s=gzip+someword`

but not
`www.example.com/s=zip` & `www.example.com/s=gzip`

The Apache error_log:

```
[Sun Jun 20 14:15:51.628805 2021] [:error] [pid 3764:tid 47658554889984] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] ModSecurity: Warning. Pattern match "(?:^|=)\\\\s*(?:{|\\\\s*\\\\(\\\\s*|\\\\w+=(?:[^\\\\s]*|\\\\$.*|\\\\$.*|<.*|>.*|\\\\'.*\\\\'|\\".*\\")\\\\s+|!\\\\s*|\\\\$)*\\\\s*(?:'|\\")*(?:[\\\\?\\\\*\\\\[\\\\]\\\\(\\\\)\\\\-\\\\|+\\\\w'\\"\\\\./\\\\\\\\]+/)?[\\\\\\\\'\\"]*(?:l[\\\\\\\\'\\"]*(?:s(?:[\\\\\\\\'\\"]*(?:b[\\\\\\\\'\\"]*_[\\\\\\\\'\\"]*r[\\\\\\\\'\\"]*e[\\\\\\\\'\\"]*l[\\\\\\\\' ..." at ARGS:s. [file "/etc/xxx/modsec_vendor_configs/OWASP3/rules/REQUEST-932-APPLICATION-ATTACK-RCE.conf"] [line "463"] [id "xxxxxx"] [msg "Remote Command Execution: Direct Unix Command Execution"] [data "Matched Data: zip  found within ARGS:s: zip someword"] [severity "CRITICAL"] [ver "OWASP_CRS/3.3.0"] [tag "application-multi"] [tag "language-shell"] [tag "platform-unix"] [tag "attack-rce"] [tag "paranoia-level/1"] [tag "OWASP_CRS"] [tag "capec/1000/152/248/88"] [tag "PCI/6.5.2"] [hostname "example.com"] [uri "/"] [unique_id "xxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"]
```

How do make an exception to this ruleset REQUEST-932-APPLICATION-ATTACK-RCE.conf to allow the above queries? I'm not RegEx savvy, and I don't know how to read it.

Comment: What have you tried? Also, what's so secret with the `[id "xxxxxx"]`?

Comment: I didn't dare to try anything since the website in question is in production, and I am afraid to break it. Concerning the "secret": it just proves my lack of knowledge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Remote Command Execution Rule with the rule id 932150 is triggered by a Unix command followed by a white space. Therefore `zip+` and `gzip+` trigger the rule, but not `zip` and `gzip` alone.

You can tune this rule by partially disabling it for your search input field `s`.
You can write the following tuning rule *after* your include of the CRS rules in the Apache conf:

```
SecRuleUpdateTargetById 932150 "!ARGS:s"
```

With this rule above you remove the check of the argument `s` from this RCE rule 932150.

A complete guide on how to handle false positives can be found here:
https://www.netnea.com/cms/apache-tutorial-8_handling-false-positives-modsecurity-core-rule-set/

Comment: I first failed to add this rule using the editor in WHM, but then through the command line I created a separate config file that I named "REQUEST-932-APPLICATION-ATTACK-RCE_CUSTOM_EXCEPTION_FOR_WORDPRESS.conf" that I then activated through WHM. Now both searches in my question works.