# ModSecurity rule 932150 false positive, remove ruby from criteria

Tags: mod-security

We have an issue with ModSecurity rule 932150 being triggered when someone searches a site for "ruby red", because (I presume) the rule thinks it's blocking potential Ruby on Rails code.

I found this:

> "The Remote Command Execution Rule with the rule id 932150 is
> triggered by a Unix command followed by a white space. Therefore zip+
> and gzip+ trigger the rule, but not zip and gzip alone."

(source: [ModSecurity OWASP CRS 3.3.0 false positives on a Wordpress site](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/251556/modsecurity-owasp-crs-3-3-0-false-positives-on-a-wordpress-site/251583#251583) )

The answer above has example code to disable checks on the argument `s`, e.g. `/search.php?s=ruby+red` but I don't want to disable checks on the full `s` argument. I'd like to only remove 'ruby' from the rule checks, so `s` is still checked but allows 'ruby'. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can remove the argument `s` from rule `932150` (`ctl:ruleRemoveTargetById=932150;ARGS:s`) if the string `s` contains the word `ruby` (`ARGS:s "@contains ruby"`):

```
SecRule ARGS:s "@contains ruby" \
    "id:10000,t:none,pass,nolog,ctl:ruleRemoveTargetById=932150;ARGS:s"
```